# Customizing Crawlera Ban Rules For Scrapy

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I'm in the process of updating a (formerly) working website crawler. It appears the website I have been crawling has introduced stricter ban rules, so I have begun to use Crawlera as an attempt to circumvent this issue.

The problem I'm having currently is that the target website is using a non-standard banning approach of doing a 302 to a standard html page. Crawlera is not detecting this as a ban and immediately stops the crawl. Is there any way I can customize what Crawlera detects as a ban, or will I need to look into another approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can ask them to insert that rule into their system and also depending on your plan, they should offer you a way to customize your own rules (still, you can ask their support, I am not completely sure).

I would say that is your best bet, if not, I would recommend creating your own [`Downloader Middlewares`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#downloader-middleware) to retry when that redirect happens. What `crawlera` does when they get a ban is to retry `n` more times (you can set that also on the headers), so you'll have to set retries to `0` and handle those yourself depending on what response you get.

Comment: That's completely right, ended up resolving this via a support ticket and they were able to add that rule to their system.